# Are there any scenarios where it would be appropriate to use an H1 in a document after an H1 has already been used?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantics

With consideration to semantics and accessibility, can I do something like this?

```
<h1>My Lightbox Demo</h1>
<h2>Thank you for trying this</h2>
<div>
    <button aria-controls="lightbox" aria-visible="false" type="button">Click me!</button>
</div>
<div id="lightbox" role="dialog" style="display: none;" aria-live="polite">
<h1>The Lightbox</h1>
<p>It worked!</p>
</div>
```

(Obviously assume that I have JavaScript that displays the lightbox when the button is clicked.) Is this okay for semantics/accessibility, or will it cause problems for screen reader users? Do I have to make the second H1 an H3? Is there any ARIA role that will permit this reuse of H1?

Comment: Why is your h2 an h2? Is it really a title or have you slipped into using h tags for presentation?

Comment: Using h1/h2/h3 are for SEO purposes (not for styling)... Therefore you should stick to one h1 tag in a page.

Comment: What might be of importance here is the `dialog` role. If it’s a correctly implemented modal dialog, its contents will be *the only accessible contents* while it’s open. This means that technically, there always is only one h1 accessible at a time! This question differs from the other one in that respect. It’s not about any section, but about a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `h1` elements, just be sure not to over use them and try to keep them to about one per section. Screen readers likely won't have issues with this. SEO should handle it fine as well as long as you don't overuse them and only use them when needed.